# Include transparent ggplot in Quarto / Rmarkdown without saving to disk

Tags: r, quarto

I can include a ggplot2 figure in a Quarto document with a transparent background if I first use `ggplot2::ggsave(bg = "transparent")`. How can I do this without having to save the image to disk?

````
---
title: "test"
theme: darkly
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
p <- ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_tile(data = data.frame(x = 1, y = 1),
                     ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      ggplot2::theme_void() +
   ggplot2::theme(
    panel.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill='transparent'), #transparent panel bg
    plot.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA), #transparent plot bg
    panel.grid.major = ggplot2::element_blank(), #remove major gridlines
    panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank(), #remove minor gridlines
    legend.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill='transparent'), #transparent legend bg
    legend.box.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill='transparent') #transparent legend panel
  )

```


# Non transparent background
```{r}
p
```

# Transparent background 

```{r}

path <- here::here("test.png")

suppressMessages(
  ggplot2::ggsave(
    plot = p,
    path = dirname(path),
    filename = basename(path),
    bg = "transparent",
    height = 4,
    scale = 2,
    dpi = 300,
    units = "in"
  )
)
  
knitr::include_graphics(path)

```
````

Comment: How about using `dev="png", dev.args=list(bg="transparent")` in the chunk options as suggested [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots)?

Comment: That works. Thank you! If you create an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this should work:

````
```{r, dev = "png", dev.args=list(bg="transparent")}
p
```
````

See [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) for a complete set of options for plots in RMarkdown.

Comment: I found related documentation [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots). If there is a more canonical source, please link to it.